# WPF bind as a command parameter the value of a local variable in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, code-behind

I am dynamically creating buttons as the program progresses. Their count is changing.

I also bind a command for every button I create.

Is there any way to pass a local variable as a parameter to the executable event?

If I want to pass `key`, what should I specify in `SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, ?)`?

```cs
foreach (int key in hotQ)
{
    Button dataButton = new Button
    {
        Content = key.ToString(),
        Width = 128,
    };
    dataButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("RunDialogCommand"));
    dataButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, ???);
}
```

Comment: `new Button { ... CommandParameter = key };`- no Binding required.

Comment: Besides that, consider using an ItemsControl with the Button in the ItemTemplate. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: @Clemens Many thanks! Your solution works